# c how to initial struct array member from another struct variable

Tags: c, gcc

example code:

```
#define ARR_SZ 1000

struct a
{
        int arr[ARR_SZ];
};

const struct a b = {
        .arr = { 1, 2, 3},
};

struct a c = {
        .arr = b.arr,
};
```

how to init b.arr to a.arr without using memcpy. above code is error when compile:

```
test.c:14:9: warning: initialization of ‘int’ from ‘const int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   14 |  .arr = b.arr,
      |         ^
test.c:14:9: note: (near initialization for ‘c.arr[0]’)
test.c:14:9: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
test.c:14:9: note: (near initialization for ‘c.arr[0]’)
```

if ARR_SZ is a fixed small value, e.g. 3, we can write for every member.

```
struct a d = {
        .arr = { b.arr[0], b.arr[1], b.arr[2] },
};
```

but if ARR_SZ is large, how do we init it.

I find a solution, add a struct wrapper

```
#define ARR_SZ 1000

struct a
{
        struct {
                int arr[ARR_SZ];
        } dummy;
};

const struct a b = {
        .dummy.arr = { 1, 2, 3},
};

struct a c = {
        .dummy = b.dummy,
};
```

Comment: It's not possible to initialize an array using an array. Or even to an assign to another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize an array with another array. You could however initialize the object `c` with `b`:

```c
struct a c = b;
```

If you need to be able to only initialize the array from `b` but other members from somewhere else, put the array in a `struct` of its own and use that type in all the `struct`s that should have this array:

```c
struct arr_holder {
    int arr[ARR_SZ];
};

struct a {
    struct arr_holder ah;
};

const struct a b = {
    .ah = {{1, 2, 3}}
};

struct a c = {.ah = b.ah };
```

If it's only `struct a` that needs this `int[ARR_SZ]` you can define it inline:

```
struct a {
    struct {
        int arr[ARR_SZ];
    } ah;
};
```